# Null/void pointer incorrect value

Tags: c, pointers, struct

We are returning a pointer to a struct in one of our functions. When we print out one of the values of the struct in our main, it is correct. However, when we pass that pointer to another function, and try to access a value, it prints out an incorrect value. It looks like that value is an address.

These calls is in our main:

```
struct temp * x = doThis();
printf("x->var1 = %d\n", x->var1);
doThat(&x);
```

In doThat, we print out:

```
void doThat(void * x)
{
    struct temp * x2 = (struct temp *) x;
    printf("x2->var1 %d", x2->var1);
}
```

The doThis function returns a void pointer and the doThat function takes in a void pointer as a parameter.

Comment: Most probably you need to `doThat(x)`.

Comment: @KerrekSB it is declared `doThat(void * x);`

Comment: Didn't it tip you off that you had to write this ridiculous cast that nobody on your team was able to explain?

Comment: By making `doThat` take a `void*` argument, you're disabling the type checking that would have avoided this problem. Why doesn't `doThat` take either a `struct temp*` or a `struct temp**`?

Comment: @KerrekSB: The cast is unnecessary; `struct temp *x2 = x;` would have compiled and had the same semantics.

Comment: Eventually time for a `typedef`?

Comment: @KeithThompson: Well, now we know that... Actually, that's even worse, because that means that an entire team just cargo-cults along without any critical questioning.

Comment: doThat must take a void pointer because our function can take in pointers to three different types of structs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `doThat` you are casting x to be a `struct temp*`, but you pass in a `struct temp**`.

You can see a similar result in this: [running code](https://ideone.com/VrONT5).

Changing from:

```
struct temp * x2 = (struct temp *) x;
printf("x2->var1 %d", x2->var1);
```

To:

```
struct temp ** x2 = (struct temp **) x;
printf("(*x2)->var1 %d", (*x2)->var1);
```

Will fix this.  Alternatively, don't pass a pointer to a pointer by changing from:

```
doThat(&x);
```

To:

```
doThat(x); /* <= Note: Don't take the address of x here! */
```

Comment: So then is casting in doThat not required?

 `struct DirectMap * x1 = x;`

This call works but instead of printing an address when printing  `x1->var1` , it is printing 0. However, print `x->var1` printed out the correct value in our doThis function and main.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This change fixed our problem.